# UPDATE column when a user renames data from another table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hey guys, how the heck do I go about doing this.

I have an address book I'm making and I'm trying to figure out how to tackle my groups. I let the users rename their groups at will. But then this complicates my life ;0

I have 2 tables. `groups` and `contacts` the groups has the group names per user. the contacts has a `group` column that says what group that contact entry belongs to.

How can I rename a group from the `groups` table and have the new name reflect in the `contacts` table so everything matches up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest changing your model.
Use `ID`s as primary keys and an intersection-table to assign your contacts to groups:

```
Groups
id
name

Contacts
id
name

Group_Contacts
group_id    -> Groups.id
contact_id  -> Contacts.id
```

Now you can change the group-name whenever you want, without updating the contacts.

---

**EDIT**: If you only want to get the contacts of a certain group, use a SELECT like this one:

```
Select c.name
From groups g
Join group_contacts gc On ( gc.group_id = g.id )
Join contacts c On ( c.id = gc.contact_id )
Where g.name = 'Your group name'
```

Comment: hmm I see, can you give me a quick php/sql scenario on how I could start my set up pls ;)

Comment: @s2xi: This would be difficult without knowing what exactly your problems are. Please try to set it up yourself, and feel free to ask another question once you are stuck...

Comment: well ok, perhaps I just need a hint/push in the right direction. When I query the database in order to get the group names I would query the groups table correct? in order to get a list of contacts i would query the contacts table correct? if I wanted to ONLY get the contacts that belong to a specific group what would I query?

Comment: where are you specifying c.name

Comment: `c` is my alias for the table `contacts`, and `name` is a column within that table. Replace it by whatever your column-name is.

Comment: ;-) After looking at it I finally understood that thank you. One quick question. I tried to say WHERE `user_id` = 2 (where 2 is the specific user logged in at the moment through a SESSION variable) but i get the error "Column `user_id` in where clause is ambiguous. What does this mean? I understand the meaning of ambiguous... I think, it means redundant sorta of right?

Comment: You need to specify your table-name (or the alias if you have one in your query): `WHERE u.user_id = 2`.

Comment: ah got it. i wasn't specifying which table for the query to look in!

Answer (score 1):

You also could use a before update trigger which first renames all entries in the contacts table to match the new name and then let the update go on